# Installshield Keywords are changed automatically

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield

I am new to installshield and I am trying to create my first installer with .ini file. But I got some problem when create .ini file in InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition with Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate)

1. I import an .ini file to InstallShield (Configure the Target System >> INI File Changes). The file's content as below:

[image]

2. When I close this tab(Tab in VS 2012) and re-open it, I got problem as below:

[image]

- The keywords are changed automatically.
- I build project, these keywords will add to .ini file when I install
- When I close all tabs, I re-open it again => No problem ???

Is there any mistake when creating .ini file? And What should I do to correct it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Valid ini files are imported to the [IniFile table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369282(v=vs.85).aspx) in the MSI allowing them to be treated as value pairs that are merged into an existing file if there is one present on disk during install.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now I resolved this problem by using another way. **Step 1** I copy .ini file to Installshield project(D:\demo\install). **Step 2** I add .ini file at Specify Application Data => Files. **Step 3** I open .isl file and find <table name="File"> to replace "D:\demo\install\UserConfiguration.ini" to "&lt;ISProjectFolder&gt;\UserConfiguration.ini".